# jsPDF method line() doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I use jsPDF in version 2.5.0. I want to draw a line. I used method line() but i have got error: "doc.line is not a function". What fuction should I use ?

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.line(10, 10, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Is it a typo? You're missing the `new` before `jsPDF();`

Comment: It is a codeigniter. I inserted the `new` before `jsPDF()` but i have got the same error.